# Why does pagination link click in Vuetify pagination component give "No matching records found" message

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

I am trying to use Vuetify datatable and pagination components to show a paginated list of projects. But when I click on pagination link to display next page of data, I am seeing the message *“No matching records found”*. Clicking on next page calls *next* method that seems to get the correct data from server side (Rub on Rails) and setting projects and pagination data properties. The relevant vue file is in github at https://github.com/navjeetc/vuejs_rails/blob/vue_component/app/javascript/parts/projects.vue

Am I not setting everything or not calling axios propertly? I am new to Vue.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution by looking at Vuetify source code. The solution is to set another prop on *v-data-table* component called *total items* e.g. `:total-items="totalProjects"` and add the data property *totalProjects* and set it appropriately. Hope it helps others.